# make check fails building glibc 2.28

Tags: glibc

I'm getting the following result when `make check`ing glibc 2.28:

```
UNSUPPORTED: elf/tst-audit10
UNSUPPORTED: elf/tst-avx512
XPASS: elf/tst-protected1a
XPASS: elf/tst-protected1b
FAIL: intl/tst-gettext
FAIL: io/ftwtest
UNSUPPORTED: math/test-double-libmvec-alias-avx512
UNSUPPORTED: math/test-double-libmvec-alias-avx512-main
UNSUPPORTED: math/test-double-libmvec-sincos-avx512
UNSUPPORTED: math/test-float-libmvec-alias-avx512
UNSUPPORTED: math/test-float-libmvec-alias-avx512-main
UNSUPPORTED: math/test-float-libmvec-sincosf-avx512
UNSUPPORTED: misc/tst-pkey
UNSUPPORTED: nptl/test-condattr-printers
UNSUPPORTED: nptl/test-mutexattr-printers
UNSUPPORTED: nptl/test-rwlockattr-printers
FAIL: nptl/tst-umask1
FAIL: posix/globtest
FAIL: posix/tst-chmod
FAIL: posix/tst-execl2
FAIL: posix/tst-execle2
FAIL: posix/tst-execlp2
FAIL: posix/tst-execv2
FAIL: posix/tst-execve2
FAIL: posix/tst-execvp2
FAIL: posix/tst-execvpe2
FAIL: posix/tst-spawn4-compat
FAIL: resolv/tst-resolv-ai_idn
FAIL: resolv/tst-resolv-ai_idn-latin1
Summary of test results:
     15 FAIL
   5904 PASS
     12 UNSUPPORTED
     17 XFAIL
      2 XPASS
Makefile:345: recipe for target 'tests' failed
make[1]: *** [tests] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/media/user123/3E2AC8A02AC85715/Linux/GLIBC/glibc-2.28'
Makefile:9: recipe for target 'check' failed
make: *** [check] Error 2
```

Here's the `configure`ation:

`../glibc-2.28/configure CC="/usr/local/bin/gcc -march=haswell -mtune=intel" CFLAGS="-O3 -fno-stack-protector -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE" --prefix=/usr --with-headers=/home/user123/linux-headers/include --disable-profile --disable-werror --with-pkgversion=2.28 --enable-add-ons`

Any suggestions on how to fix it? It was compiled with GCC 9.0.0 (trunk), but the compilation presented no errors.